# Close socket when client disconnects so it can be reused c#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, sockets

I have a Chat room application which is fully working but when it comes to the client disconnecting the socket remains open and soon the 30 sockets are filled out so no more clients can connect, I have had a stab in the dark at trying to find the index ip of each socket client which is connect to disconnect them when the disconnect button is called but I have no idea how to actually do this as it is stored in a socket Array and not in an Array.

This is the piece on my server where I want to disconnect the socket/ client from.

```
 public AsyncCallback pfnWorkerCallBack;
        private Socket m_mainSocket;
        private Socket[] m_workerSocket = new Socket[30];
        private int m_clientCount = 0;
        public System.Net.Sockets.Socket m_currentSocket;
        public byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[1024];
        string NickName;

public void OnDataReceived(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        try
        {

            SocketPacket socketData = (SocketPacket)asyn.AsyncState;
            int iRx = 0;
            // Complete the BeginReceive() asynchronous call by EndReceive() method
            // which will return the number of characters written to the stream 
            // by the client
            iRx = socketData.m_currentSocket.EndReceive(asyn);
            char[] chars = new char[iRx + 1];
            System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            int charLen = d.GetChars(socketData.dataBuffer,
                                     0, iRx, chars, 0);
            System.String szData = new System.String(chars);
            string text = (szData);

            string temp = szData.Substring(0, 10);

            if (temp == "Disconnect")
            {

                int bum = szData.Length-12;
               temp = szData.Substring(11, bum);

               int no = // find the index of the ip 

                m_clientCount --;
               ArrayList temparray = new ArrayList();
               temparray.AddRange(m_workerSocket.ToArray());

                temparray.RemoveAt(no);
                temparray.Add(null);

               int i = 0;
               foreach (Socket content in temparray)
                {
                  m_workerSocket[i] = content;
                  i++;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Object objData = text;
                byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(objData.ToString());
                for (int i = 0; i < m_clientCount; i++)
                {

                    if (m_workerSocket[i] != null)
                    {
                        if (m_workerSocket[i].Connected)
                        {
                            m_workerSocket[i].Send(byData);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Invoke(new Action(() => richTextBoxSendMsg.AppendText(szData)));
                Invoke(new Action(() => richTextBoxSendMsg.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)));
                // Continue the waiting for data on the Socket
                WaitForData(socketData.m_currentSocket);
            }
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Log(0, "1", "\nOnDataReceived: Socket has been closed\n");
        }


        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
        }

    }
```

And the Client side of the Disconnect call

```
private void buttonDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Object objData = "Disconnect " + GetIP();
        byte[] byData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(objData.ToString());
        if (m_clientSocket != null)
        {
            m_clientSocket.Send(byData);

            txtBoxMsg.Clear();
        }
        if (m_clientSocket != null)
        {
            m_clientSocket.Close();
            m_clientSocket = null;
            UpdateControls(false);
        }

    }
```

I hope this is enough information as I really am clue how to do this.. 
Thank you for any and all input/ constructive criticism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var clientSocket = (Socket)asyn.AsyncState;
for (int i = 0; i < m_workerSocket.Count(); i++)
{
    if (m_workerSocket[i] == clientSocket)
    {
        var sockets = new List<Socket>(m_workerSocket);
        sockets.RemoveAt(i);
        m_workerSocket = sockets.ToArray();
        break;
    }
}
clientSocket.Close()
```

Comment: I have Implemented your suggested code and it has come back with 2 errors. The first being Error 2 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'RemoteAt' and no extension method 'RemoteAt' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found. And Error 1 Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group' So I have no idea. But thank you.

Comment: Sorry, there were a couple typos...  I edited the code to fix them

Comment: The edit fixed the one problem but it still claims that .RemoveAt is not a definition for the System.Array which sucks but this is far closer to finishing my chat room than earlier.

Comment: I see, forgot that I use an extension method for RemoveAt.

Comment: Awesome the new edit worked. Thanks you so much for your time it is much appreciated.